# Firefox Displaying Blury Images

Tags: firefox

[image]

This is a screnshot of my firefox web browsers, changing the size of the browser or zooming in does not fix this problem. I have not changed any settings

Answer (score 0):

Try Uninstalling and then installing the newest version of Firefox. Tell me if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question for anybody who would like to know

Option -> Advanced -> General

Uncheck the "Use hardware acceleration when available" box